# Trigger Show event of file upload dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to show file upload dialog on click of a button thats not the part of input[type="file"] how can i do this?

Basically i want to stylize the file upload control of html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternate way to style file inputs using JavaScript but no Flash:

http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2007/09/10/styling_file_inputs_with_css_and_the_dom

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there is no way to do this for security reasons.

You may be able to do it using a Flash-based uploader like [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org). It obviously needs Flash installed and functions in a slightly different way than normal file uploads.

Answer (score 0):

two days ago i was dealing with the same thing. I spotted [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)

it allows you to have custom button for upload and ability to style your progress bar. it makes an ajax call to a php script. it also has loads of options from restricting file types/sizes/etc.

pretty happy i found it. same as pekka said this one also uses a flash gateway to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`document.formname.file.click()`  works but not in Opera  i am still searching the net to solve.